# Same text for <h1> and <h2>

Tags: seo, html, heading

What do you think about having the same content for H1 and H2 tag in the article?  It seems like keyword stuffing, right? Example:

```
<h1>Bananas <span>Musa × paradisiaca</span></h1>

<h2>Bananas <span>Musa × paradisiaca</span></h2>

<h2>Description</h2>  
<p>Bananas are long and yellow. Bananas are long and yellow.</p>

<h2>Taste</h2>  
<p>Bananas are delicious. Bananas are delicious. Bananas are delicious.</p>
```

Do you think this is a bad practice? This is how graphic layout is made for a page so the title should repeat itself (there is a tall image between them), and I'm wondering if it would be better to have markup something like this (in this case `<p>`), but styled as so it looks like `h2`.

Would you suggest something else instead of `<p>` which better suits a title consisted of a 2-3 words? This is a purely design based idea and I wouldn't even mind telling search engines to not index this line.

```
<h1>Bananas <span>Musa × paradisiaca</span></h1>

<p class="h2">Bananas <span>Musa × paradisiaca</span></p>

<h2>Description</h2>  
<p>Bananas are long and yellow. Bananas are long and yellow.</p>

<h2>Taste</h2>  
<p>Bananas are delicious. Bananas are delicious. Bananas are delicious.</p>
```

(Span has a `display: block` set so that it goes to next line)

Comment: That's a lot of questions! It appears you're looking for SEO advice - it might help if you read up on the subject of on-page SEO. I recommend starting here: http://upcity.com/blog/ultimate-guide-developing-actionable-seo-audit/

Comment: Both examples are terrible! Search is not about keywords and stuffing them in anywhere you can. It is about whole language. Write naturally for people and not machines. The more thoroughly you write about a topic the better. Your keyword repetition is disastrous and will fail miserably.

Comment: The text inside paragraph is only lorem ipsum kind of example... I am asking for advice with what html tag should I enclose the second text so that it doesn't  seem like a mere duplicate. For example it would be interesting to have something like display: none which works inversely, so that it is visible to a human, but to a bot it isn't...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don’t use another heading element for the duplicated content.** Headings (`h1`-`h6`) serve various purposes (generating the document outline, navigation for screen reader users, etc.). A duplicated heading is useless and can be bothersome or lead to confusion.

Using a different element and styling it according to your intended design is the correct way. Using `p` for this seems to be appropriate; otherwise the meaningless `div`.

To make clear that this text is not part of the section’s main content, you could use the [`header` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-header-element) to group the heading, the duplicated heading text, and the image (assuming that the image is also part of the header).

To make clear that the duplicated text is not relevant, and only serves an aesthetic purpose, you can use the [WAI-ARIA `presentation` role](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#index-aria-presentation).

So your section would contain:

```html
<header>
  <h1>Bananas <span>Musa × paradisiaca</span></h1>
  <img src="tall-image.png" alt="" />
  <p role="presentation">Bananas <span>Musa × paradisiaca</span></p>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

This does come off as keyword stuffing.

Think about heading tags as a table of contents for the rest of the content on the page. When stripping away all other informations on the page. Your headings should be able to read as a table of contents.

When looking at a table of contents where keywords are used over and over again, it is impossible do determine what supplemental content should be included under each section of the table of content.